# Python: Passing a class instance to an external function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have come across a python project that commonly calls external functions from class methods and passes the class instance and some other parameters to the external function.

The method used is shown in `method_one` below and I have never come across this implementation before. Using locals to get both the local method parameters and the `self` class instance seems strange to say the least. The code then relies upon the dictionary keys being named correctly i.e. the same as the parameters of the external function (`some_function`).

To me, the obvious, simpler direct alternative is `method_two` but even over that I would prefer either

1. making `some_function` a method of `ExampleClass1` so it has direct access to self, or
2. passing only the required attributes of the `ExampleClass1` instance to `some_function`.

Example code:

```
class ExampleClass1(object):
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = something

    def method_one(self, param_1, param_2):
        all_params = locals()
        all_params['example_self'] = all_params.pop('self')
        some_function(**all_params)

    def method_two(self, param_1, param_2):
        some_function(self, param_1, param_2)


def some_function(example_self, param_1, param_2):
    print(example_self.something, param_1, param_2)


e = ExampleClass1("do")
e.method_one(1, "a")
e.method_two(2, "b")
```

So,

1. Is there any reason to be using `method_one` that I'm not aware of?
2. How would you offer advice on the best practice for this situation?

Comment: I'd say example one is just really bad practice. Don't do that and be careful with the code where you found it. In Python, we have a saying that explicit is better than implicit, example one breaks that principle, severly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `self` as a parameter to external functions is a totally standard practice.  I'm a little unclear why the call to `locals()` is used and why keys are being shuffled around, but that's a separate matter.  In general, I find that if you're using `locals()`, then 9 times out of 10 the code you're writing can be simpler.  Notable exception being metaprogramming, which is another topic.

One example that I use this for is when you want to separate out code into several modules rather than have one large class with a bunch of methods.  There's a lot of ways to organize code, but one approach that I use is to segregate functions to other modules based on their domain, and then pass `self` to those functions for their use.

Concrete example: a server object accepting requests can have the routes handling those requests live elsewhere, and then delegate the actual business logic to the external route functions.  If those routes need the server object, though, then you may want to pass `self` (being the server) to them.  You could make an argument they should just be methods then, but that's a matter of code style and depends a lot on exact use case.

In general, passing `self` around isn't a bad practice when used appropriately.

Comment: Yes, totally agree about passing `self` being normal practice. I was just wondering if there was something special about using the locals() method - doesn't appear so! Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'd rank using `locals()` and `globals()` up there with `exec()`: to be avoided 99.9% of the time, and the .1% of the time has to be really really justified.  Anything having to do with looking at "the state of the program execution" from a meta level is generally ill-advised because it's not explicit at all what you're doing.